# Mocha does not rerun my tests after changes

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Using a test environment with

- `chokidar` (to trigger test files on changes with a *watcher* `chokidar` variable),
- `node.js` (to output tests result in browser),
- `mocha+chai` (test suite),
- using a custom reporter (as described in [Using Mocha programmatically](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically))

As the test file is changed, *watcher* catch the event, and should rerun the test.

**Problem**: My test is executed only once !

When trying to run my test for a second time (when the file has changed on disk the second time), `mocha` do not reprocess the test as in the first time.  I suspect that I should reset some internal runner properties, but looking in the mocha github repository, I do not seem to find the correct method to call.  Note that my reporter "class" only received 1 event from `mocha` runner.on("end", ...) on the second watcher wakup.

```
watcher.on('change', function(path, stats) {
   // ...
   console.log('-----File ' + path + ' has been changed ' + "[" + stats.size + "b]" );
   Mocha             = require('mocha');
   Mocha.prototype.printFiles = function(){
     console.log("Existing files = ");
     console.log( this.files );
     return this;
   };   
   var mocha = new Mocha({
    bail: false
   });
   mocha.reporter("/dirs/MyReporter.js");
   mocha.addFile("/dirs/my-test.js");
   mocha.run(function(failures){
   });
   // ...
});
```

How can I ask (method call) Mocha to reset its assumptions of my precedent run to rerun my test as the first time ?

Comment: [Issue solved by Travis Jeffery on github mocha repository.](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/995#issuecomment-27659485)

Answer (score 0):

//add mocha -w to your test script
"scripts": {
"test":  "mocha -w"
}